# Validate posted data in node with joi

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

So I am trying to validate data on my post request.
For this I want to use joi, but it seems there is something I am missing somewhere.
Here is my post request:

```
app.post('/new-comp', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const validation = schemaComp.validate(req.body)
  // need to declare an if/else statement to manage the error
  // for now, console.logs the info that data is not valid
  const data = await new CompetitionModel(req.body)
  console.log(validation)
  res.json(data)
})
```

As I put in comment, I need to do some if/else statement to manage the validation (as it seems to validate the data, but doesn't stop the posting)

However, I am not sure how to do this and all the ways I tried were leading me to an error.
I am very much a beginner with this and any advise will be appreciated.
In addition please find below my joi file

```
export const Joi = require('joi')

export const schemaComp = Joi.object().keys({
  event_id: Joi.string().required(),
  compName: Joi.string().required(),
  place: Joi.string().required(),
  time: Joi.string().required(),
  subscriptions: [
    {
      id: Joi.string().required(),
      event_id: Joi.string().required(),
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      surname: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  ],
  date: Joi.date().required(),
  cost: {
    currency: Joi.string().required(),
    amount: Joi.number().required(),
  },
})
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can try this
`const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schemaComp);
if(result.error){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate like this, `{ abortEarly: false }` to throw errors for all validations

```js
const { error } = schemaComp.validate(inputObj, { abortEarly: false });
  if (error) {
    // handle your errors here
  }
```